# Cannot delete folder because it's open in another process

Tags: windows, directory

I cannot delete a folder that's located on a network path because "The file is open in another process". I have managed to recursively delete the folder contents with powershell, but not the root folder itself.

I have ran openfiles.exe on that remote path, did not find anything open under that name.

Tried ProcessExplorer, ProcessHacker, Unlocker, Handle, and other several tools but I was unable to find what's locking that folder.

Note that the folder is shared on an IBM Blade so I cannot connect to it via RPC or other remote means like I could connect to a server (from Computer Management > Shared Folders for example)

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to delete the folder in the end by following the below steps:

```
1) ended explorer.exe process
2) pressed CTRL+SHITF+ESC to run Task Manager
3) ran powershell.exe as an admin
4) ran get-item -path "\\server\drive$\folder" | remove-item -force -verbose
5) started explorer.exe back
```